# Why does ng-style in angularjs run incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-style like the image below
[ng-style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6hWG.png)

Why count not show 3, 4 but 22, 23

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-style="countStyle()">Welcome {{count}}</h1>
<h1 ng-style="countStyle()">Welcome {{count}}</h1>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.myObj = {
    "color" : "white",
    "background-color" : "coral",
    "font-size" : "60px",
    "padding" : "50px"
  }
  var i = 2;
  $scope.count = 1;
  $scope.countStyle = function(){
    i += 1;
    $scope.count = i;
    return $scope.myObj;
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYYiH.png)

Answer (score 0):

22 (2 + 20)

This is because each of your code below will reach the limitation of digest loop Threshold， which is 10:

```
<h1 ng-style="countStyle()">Welcome {{count}}</h1>
<h1 ng-style="countStyle()">Welcome {{count}}</h1>
```

Because you have 2 bindings above, so it will run digest cycle 20 times and abort.

Try to remove one of line above, like:

```
<h1 ng-style="countStyle()">Welcome {{count}}</h1>
```

Then it will display 12. (2+10)

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/8b2tocf9/)

This is because your method will always be invoked on every digest cycle, please try to add console.log in your `$scope.countStyle` method.

It will throws an error called: [angular.min.js:124 Error: [$rootScope:infdig]](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2214%22,%22oldVal%22:%2212%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2215%22,%22oldVal%22:%2213%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2216%22,%22oldVal%22:%2214%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2217%22,%22oldVal%22:%2215%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2218%22,%22oldVal%22:%2216%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2219%22,%22oldVal%22:%2217%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2220%22,%22oldVal%22:%2218%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2221%22,%22oldVal%22:%2219%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2222%22,%22oldVal%22:%2220%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function(c,%5Cne,g,f)%7Bg%3Dd%26%26f%3Ff%5B0%5D:a(c,e,g,f);return%20b(g,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%2223%22,%22oldVal%22:%2221%22%7D%5D%5D)

This means the 10 $digest() iterations reached.

Comment: How to display results 3 and 4

Comment: Directly count in controller, instead of a function binding in countStyle

Comment: Actually i can only see your issues, i don't understand what you are going to do. For display 2 and 3, please see the updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/8b2tocf9/